# Android <intent-filter> works for <activity /> but not for <receiver />

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I have an `Activity` with multiple `<intent-filter>` tags:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NFCActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_nfc" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="secure"
            android:pathPrefix="/a000000004"
            android:port="0"
            android:scheme="nfc" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="nfc" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

This works as expected, the activity launches as a transaction is detected.

The same thing can't be said when working with a `BroadcastReceiver`, the `onReceive` method is not invoked:

```
<receiver
        android:name="carta.NfcReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="secure"
            android:pathPrefix="/a000000004"
            android:port="0"
            android:scheme="nfc" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="nfc" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Activity intents and Broadcast intents are different things. You cannot receive one in the other.

Comment: in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515017/android-receiver-for-multiple-actions they say it is possible, otherwise what can I use to handle those kind of actions ?

Comment: how do you call `sendBroadcast()` ?

Comment: I don't, normally it's registered in the manifest, so when the same action is executed it is automatically called. like the ones used for handling SMS

Comment: @ElJazouli: the linked question is unrelated. My point is that the actions that you are referring to (`TRANSACTION_*`) are Activity actions, which cannot be picked by a Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: I see, so I have to do it with an Intent, thank you very much, you can post it as an answer if you'd like so I can confirm it

Comment: I have tried the code with activity.But it is not working.Can you tell me what is needed to work this with activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The same thing can't be said when working with a BroadcastReceiver, the onReceive method is not invoked:

That is because those actions are being used by some other process in `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`. You cannot respond to `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` with a `BroadcastReceiver`.